# Ip block magento admin for https

Tags: .htaccess, admin, block

We are trying to protect our admin url /admin/ with a ip block in the htacces. So that we can only approach the admin url from a single ip adres and other people cannot get there. We found the following code that makes it work in http so without ssl, but our site has ssl (https) and with the following code it does not work there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.1.1.1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// %{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

I am no expert in setting up rewrite rules and things in htacces. Is there anyone that knows how to change this code to block the admin url for a https shop?

Comment: We cannot help with such a vague question. We'd have to know what URIs you want to rewrite and what not, also what _exactly_ you mean by "This does not work".

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arkascha. Ok so what I do want to do is that only curtain ip adresses can visit the admin page for security reasons. So that only from our office it can be reached. With the code that I sended in the question you can do this for websites without ssl certificates (http), now I am looking for the code for a website with ssl (https). So in the example above only ip 1.1.1.1 can acces the url admin and I try to get this to work with https. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: No, sorry, it does not make things much clearer. So much was clear from your question. You did not answer to my question what you actually mean by "This does not work". Certainly redirecting to http protocol from an https site is questionable. Also there is an obvious syntax error in the RewriteRule. But I assume you know those things. So the question for us is: what is wrong with the rule for you? Oh, and please do not add additional information in comments. Add it to the question. There is an `edit` link below your question for that. _Use it._

Comment: It probably makes sense for you to take a look into your http servers error log file as a first step.

Comment: just rewrote the question to make it more clear

Comment: But you still do not answer to questions. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not really clear what your specific issues is, but I will try a *guess* to answer this. It might be that your issue is not solved by this. If so, then the issue is something else which you still did not address. I asked above in the comments what you actually mean by "This does not work". A *precise* description of the issue is important to ge *precise* answers.

Anyway, I don't see a reason why you have to deal with protocol and host name in an explicit manner. Just rewrite everything in a relative manner and all should be fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.1\.1\.1$
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]
```

Note: instead of a specific IP address you probably want to specify an address range. So some prefix maybe like `^1\.1`.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think you did get the question with this and I also changed the question to make the "this does not work" part more clear. Now after your answer we will first try to place it in the http servers host, so that it is placed in a cleaner way.